# Matplotlib 1.3 axes.lineswidth glitch. How to use the github fix?

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I'm experiencing an issue for thick linewidths, as described here:
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2542
I think the issue first appeared after I updated to MPL 1.3.

A minimum working example is:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
plt.rcParams.update({"axes.linewidth": 20.0 })
plt.plot(range(5))
plt.show()
```

Basically, for thick lines, white squares appear in the corners. On Github, a fix has been recommended: "use projecting caps for axes spine". However, I can't see how to execute this command in the above code to fix the issue. Is this possible please?

I also note on github that a pull request was issued. What exactly does this mean for end-users of matplotlib - can we download a fix or do we have to wait for the next release of the MPB package?

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to clone the repository and install from the v1.3.x branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the topic of getting the fix from the git repository, you will want to use the command `git cherry-pick`. With it you can pull in the specific changes from that pull request. See: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html